# How to use diff tool to take a diff between directories with libraries and source?

Tags: linux, directory, diff

I would like to know if i can use the **diff** tool to take the difference between two folders which contain sources as well as libraries and executable.

Right now i gave

> diff -Naur dir1/ dir2/

It is comparing the executables within the directories and is dumping junk values.
Is there any way to remove the libraries and executable while comparing these directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the -a switch.

```
diff -Nur dir1/ dir2/
```

This will only output 'Files dir1/afile and dir2/afile differ' on binary files.